# Why is this if/else error appearing in script but not in console?

Tags: r

In this piece of code:

```
q7 <- function (x) {
  if (is.numeric (x) == FALSE) {stop ("Input is non-numeric.")}
  if (all (x > 0) == FALSE) {stop ("Input has negative values.")}
  sum <- 0
  while (sum <= 100) {
    if (x[1] > 50) {next}
    else if (x[1] %% 2 == 0) {sum <- sum + (x[1] / 2)}
    else {sum <- sum + x[1]}
    x <- x [x[2]:length (x)]
  }
}
```

Used for example as `q7 (c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))`, I get this error:

```
Error in if (x[1] > 50) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I think the condition here couldn't be simpler and I must be missing some R heuristic, because obviously in the console;

```
> x <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
> x[1] > 50
[1] FALSE
```

So simple.
What is going on?

Comment: I want to omit the first value in `x` in every itteration, is there a way that wouldn't mess everything up?

Comment: Of course, this eluded me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick diagnose with `debug` shows the problem is with

```
x <- x[x[2]:length(x)]
```

After the first iteration this will be a vector of `NA`. Then in the next iteration, when you check `x[1] > 50`, you are in fact doing `NA > 50`, thus you get the error.

After checking with you, you simply want to remove the first value of `x`. So why not use

```
x <- x[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing x[2] to just 2 will do it.

```
x <- x [2:length (x)]
```

Because of the 'next' statement you will end up with an infinite loop, since from x[1] = 60 onward, it will keep moving to the next iteration of the while loop (forever). Maybe you wanted to use 'break'.